# Is there a word for "specify/determine something in terms of something else"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I am attempting to translate a greek document and there is a concept that doesn't seem to translate to a given english word; one that I know at least.

It more or less says:

" Fiscus -a legal term- cannot be determined in terms of its own self; it can only be defined in terms of imperium, its direct opposite"...

This might be enough to convey the meaning of the sentence but I'm looking for something better. Is there a single word, or a better way to say "determined in terms of itself" (perhaps self-determined?) and "determined in terms of someting else" ?

Comment: *Self-explanatory?. Self-defining?* or alternatively *dependent* ?

Comment: I don't think you want the word "determined," do you? Why not use "defined" instead of "determined"?

Comment: Does "Fiscus" refer to its latin meaning, i.e. the one of three branches of the public treasury under the Roman Empire that was most under imperial control or  to a more recent sense related to taxation ?

Comment: The statement more or less makes no sense.  *Fiscus* is the state treasury; *imperium* is state power.  They're  not opposites.  Consider the Latin aphorism *Ubi fiscus, ibi imperium*, roughly "Where there's money, there's power."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might go with something like:

- *Fiscus*, a legal term, cannot be defined in ***positive terms***; it can only be defined negatively in terms of *imperium*, its direct opposite.

You might say that the word cannot be ***defined positively***, rather, it can only be ***defined negatively***.

You might also say that it cannot be ***defined directly***, rather, it can only be ***defined indirectly***, using *imperium*.